# MICROSOFT.XMLDOM -- selecting a node that contains a specific node

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic, xmldom

Here is an extract from the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<usa_map_locator>
    <map_data>
        <state>
            <id>2</id>
            <link/>
        </state>
        <state>
            <id>3</id>
            <link/>
        </state>
    </map_data>
</usa_map_locator>
```

I need to assign a value to the link node for state 2 (or 3 or 4 or 5 and so on). I am using MICROSOFT.XMLDOM object to read the source XML and need the right method(s) to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doc.selectSingleNode("/usa_map_locator/map_data/state/id[.='2']::parent()/link").innerText = "link value";

Comment: `doc.selectSingleNode("/usa_map_locator/map_data/state/id[.='2']/../link").innerText = ""` worked

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't work for a number of reasons try this:-

```
 doc.selectSingleNode("/usa_map_locator/map_data/state[id='2']/link").text = "value"
```

Comment: I managed to get the first answer to work for my needs. Your's is correct too.